# PHP - urldecode. Different behavior with Wikipedia

Tags: php, urldecode

all.
I have different behavior of function **urldecode()** in **PHP 5.2.x**. Especially you will be able to see it with Wikipedia as good example.

Firstly, my page where I have results of that function has meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Than I'm using function:

```
$url = urldecode($url);
echo $url;
```

Here is example of $url variable:

- http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82

  It will be decoded good. Result: "Брест"
- http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CC%EE%EB%EE%E4%E5%F7%ED%EE

  It will not be converted good. Result: ���������, but should be "Молодечно".

What's wrong? Why? I'm tried to use all functions from function.urldecode.php at PHP web-site, but it didn't give me any successful results

Here is quick example of code to test in PHP:

```
<?php
$url = array();

$url[] = "http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82";
$url[] = "http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CC%EE%EB%EE%E4%E5%F7%ED%EE";

foreach ($url as $value) :
    echo urldecode($value) . "<br/>";
endforeach;
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE --- this is "Молодечно"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where you've taken that url, but the correct utf-8 one for "Молодечно" is:

```
$url = 'http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE';

echo urldecode($url);
```

Your one is cp1251 encoded

Comment: Yes, sorry, that url gives me search engine which I use.

Comment: But how can I determine which charset url has?

Answer (score 1):

As said zerkms, the following url is cp1251 encoded. To convert it to UTF-8, just use this:

```
 $url = 'http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CC%EE%EB%EE%E4%E5%F7%ED%EE';
 echo iconv("Windows-1251","UTF-8",urldecode($url));

 //output:  Молодечно
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thank you! But may be you can suggest how to determine which charset URL has?

Comment: @Peter: you cannot be sure 100% about which encoding is used, but you can try to guess. There are a lot of topics here about it. You can start your exploration with http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding